# Insert list in listbox

Tags: c#, list, class, listbox

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to explore in C#, however I try to add a list in a listbox.

The error that I'm having is : `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
Any idea how to resolve this?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        something a = something iets();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
// part1
        class something {

            public List<string> testing { get  ; set; }
        }

// part2
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            a.testing.Add("programming");
            a.testing.Add("over");
            a.testing.Add("something");



            foreach (string i in a.testing)
            { listBox1.Items.Add(i); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to allocate memory for list<string> Testing write now its null and you cant add value in null.

Comment: `something a = something iets();` looks suspicious.  I wouldn't expect it to compile

Comment: We'll know what you mean if you type _C#_...

Answer (score 3):

You have to initialize `testing` at some point before accessing it.

Maybe you could add a constructor to the something class.

```
public something()
{
  testing = new List<string>();
}
```

and as pointed in the comments above, replace

```
something a = something iets();
```

with this below.

```
something a = new something(); //this should be the correct thing.
```

Comment: ah i forgot to rename that last word. something a = new something(); Sorry about that and thank you, ill try to build on further with your example

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason you're getting a `NullReferenceException` is that the list of strings in the class `something` is not initialized. You could define a parameterless constructor and initialize the list there.

```
public something()
{
    testing = new List<string>();
}
```

You might also want to know that the first letter of class and property names are usually capitalized (`class Something` instead of `class something`, for instance).

Furthermore, you could use the `AddRange` method instead of adding the strings one by one in a foreach loop.

```
listbox1.Items.AddRange(a.testing.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the more ways i know on how to implement arrays or list into other objects such as listbox textbox etc... the better. i really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your class "something" never initializes the List.  What you should do is this.

```
class something{
private List<string> _list;
public something(){
    _list = new List<string>();
}

public List<string> testing {get{return _list;} set{_list = value;}}
```

}

OR before your line of a.testing.Add() you should do a.testing = new List();

Comment: Ah, omg.. thank you, now i see why i receive a "not instance" error its because i didnt initialize it. Well we all had/have to learn the errors someday xD thank you